# Arduino-controlled Pet Door Lock

Tags: arduino-uno

Have a problem: new house but it gets super-windy and the doggy doors' magnets are too weak and blow open. Can't use bigger magnets because the doggies are too small.

So I thought I'd reinforce the pet-doors with a latch.

Next problem: the dogs are too dumb to learn wait for the doors to open. So the release mechanism must be rapid.

My plan was:
Arduino - uno or beetle/leonardo
motion sensor or ultrasonic sensors x2 (one inside and one outside) -> arduino -> relay ->wall power supply -> electromagnet release (normally on)

- only the electromagnet gets super hot, so may not be best. Do servos or solenoids open fast? as in < 1s

Anyone have any suggestions on a  better way?? THanks so much!

Comment: Solenoids are probably your best bet. Get a spring loaded one with a chamfered actuator designed for door locks. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Solenoid-Electromagnetic-Electric-Cabinet-Intelligent/dp/B07GSV92YJ